# Foreground service killed on Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I'm struggling with my Foreground Service. On my device (Redmi 5 Plus, Android 8.1.0) the service notification is no longer visible when 
app is removed from recent apps. On other devices (Android 5.0.1, Android 7.0) and emulator (android 8.1 - api 27) the notification is still visible when app is removed from recent apps.

From main activity, I'm using `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intent)` to start my service.

Below the code of the foreground service:

```
package com.ngallazzi.bluetoothtests.services

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.app.*
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW
import android.util.Log
import com.ngallazzi.blemanager.managers.DeviceScanningListener
import com.ngallazzi.blemanager.managers.InRangeDetectionManager
import com.ngallazzi.bluetoothtests.MainActivity
import com.polidea.rxandroidble2.RxBleDevice


/**
 * BluetoothTests
 * Created by Nicola on 12/17/2018.
 * Copyright © 2018 Zehus. All rights reserved.
 */

class DeviceDetectionService : Service() {

    private lateinit var detectionManager: InRangeDetectionManager

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        detectionManager = InRangeDetectionManager(this)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent != null) {
            val action = intent.action

            when (action) {
                ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> {
                    startForegroundService()
                    detectionManager.startDeviceScanning(object : DeviceScanningListener {
                        @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
                        override fun onDeviceFound(device: RxBleDevice) {
                            device.establishConnection(false).subscribe({
                                Log.v(TAG, "Connected")
                                displayNotification(getNotification("Connected with: {${device.name}}"))
                            }, {
                                displayNotification(getNotification("An error occurred: {$it.message!!}"))
                            })
                        }

                        override fun onError(message: String?) {
                            displayNotification(getNotification("An error occurred: {$message}"))
                        }

                    })
                }
                ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE -> {
                    stopForegroundService()
                }
            }

        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun startForegroundService() {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(SEARCHING_DEVICES_MESSAGE))
        Log.v(TAG, "Device detection service started")
    }

    private fun getNotification(message: String): Notification {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            createChannel()

        val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_NAME).apply {
            setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation)
            setContentTitle(message)
            setContentIntent(getMainActivityPendingIntent())
        }

        return mBuilder
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build()
    }

    private fun displayNotification(notification: Notification) {
        val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    private fun getMainActivityPendingIntent(): PendingIntent {
        // Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        // Create the TaskStackBuilder
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        return pendingIntent!!
    }

    @TargetApi(26)
    @Synchronized
    private fun createChannel() {
        val mNotificationManager = this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

        val mChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_NAME, SEARCHING_DEVICES_MESSAGE, importance)

        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
    }

    private fun stopForegroundService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stop foreground service.")

        // Stop foreground service and remove the notification.
        stopForeground(true)

        // Stop the foreground service.
        stopSelf()
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = DeviceDetectionService::class.java.simpleName

        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
        const val ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "start_service"
        const val ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = "stop_service"
        const val CHANNEL_NAME = "DEVICE_DETECTION_SERVICE"
        const val SEARCHING_DEVICES_MESSAGE = "Searching in range device"
    }
}
```

And here there is my manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.ngallazzi.bluetoothtests">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:name=".App"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".services.DeviceDetectionService" android:enabled="true"/>

        <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

What am I missing? Is it something bound to Background Execution Limits?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#top_of_page)? Actually I didn’t try but reading [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) it seems that you need to call also your service startForeground() within 5 secs after the call you do. It doesn’t seem you call it, but I’m in front of a “blond” (beer) and I could have missed something.

Comment: @shadowsheep Thanks I read it but I'm calling startForeground() in the startForegroundService() method, as soon as I get ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE command from start activity. Enjoy your beer and thanks for your contribute :)

Comment: Ahah! Now I see ^^', I'm in front of my laptop. It looks good to me. Since it's not so clear from your question, do you think the problem is specific to the API level (i.e. Oreo) or the device? I'm wondering if on another device with API level >= 26 your code will work as expected. May I suggest you to try your service without all the BLE part. I've just tried on an Emulator running API level 27 and if I kill the app the service is still alive. Btw, why do you wanna have a foreground service still running when you kill your app? With all new restrictions coming it would be a pain to mantain.

Comment: @shadowsheep Thanks for following me up :). Probably the problem it's specific for android version 8.1.0 and does not occur on the other devices I tested. I've already tried the service without the BLE part, same behavior :(. The purpose of the foreground service is scanning for a specific ble device and auto connected to it once the device comes in range with my phone

Comment: What do you mean "by killing the app". There is no such thing for Android developer like "killing the app" - be precise.

Comment: @Marian Pazdzioch I mean removing the app from the list of the app in background execution on my phone

Comment: You mean removing app from recent apps? Then please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that. I think that's common language saying "killing the app" and by that I mean killing the app process. This doesn't happen when the app is in the background (in the recent app list) and its process is still alive. My problem is that when the app process is killed the service does not survive

Comment: Removing from recents is not the same as stopping the app's process. This is why I asked to be precise. The question is still not precise. If you want us to help you, please let us do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186298/discussion-between-nicola-gallazzi-and-marian-pazdzioch).

Comment: did you check that createChannel works well and other notifications works? plus clean up the code

Comment: @MarianPaździoch think that the problem is related specifically to my device, on emulator with api level 27 the app works as expected. I don't think that the problem is related to createChannel function, the app works well also for android Pie (api level 28)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> **Step 1**) Add this tag `android:process` in your service class tag in
> **android:process="classname"**
> manifest file

then in service class do this

> **Step 2**) Override `onTaskRemoved()` in service class
>
> Restart the service using alarm manager
>
> **Step 3**) Ask user to enable **autorun** **persmission** which has customized os

If user enables it , then your service will run after the app is killed.

[Link for autoenable permission code](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter)

**Note:- Copy this code and paste it , Kotlin converter will automatically convert it**

Comment: It seems a little bit overkilling to me but I will give it a try :)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes :(

Comment: did you test it after allowing autorun permission ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't do it by using your library but I set up the permissions from app settings on my phone

Comment: Updated with manifest, I've tried also with android:name=".services.DeviceDetectionService"
            android:process=":services.DeviceDetectionService"

Comment: please update your DeviceDetectionService  class here

Comment: thanks but I've already tried this option and nothing changes

Comment: How can I detect autorun enable or disable?.